# Exporting ggplot with extrafont using ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave, extrafont

To have my plot match the font used for my writing, I added the font via the `extrafont` package. Thus, I performed the following procedure:

```
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device = "win")
```

This allowed me to change the font of my plot via a change of the theme. So far, so good. Now I want to export the plot using the `ggsave()` function. Unfortunately, the plot is exported without the new font, looking like this:
[Output without font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W53rg.png)

However, I want it to look like this:
[Wanted look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDtQc.png)

Now, I read up and found some people with similar issues. However, none of the proposed solutions worked for me. I tried to use the `jpeg()` and `png()` functions, however, the resulting quality is extremely bad; even when changing size and dpi manually, it does not seem to have an effect.
Also, exporting as a pdf is not an option for me.

Comment: If you're going for raster output you might try the [{ragg}](https://ragg.r-lib.org/) package.